# Fullcalendar v4 re-render resources function not working

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I was trying to add multiple filters on resources grid view of full calendar V4, But I didn't get any references. Here I attached sample codes that i have tried.

[image]

```
resourceRender: function(renderInfo) {
   return renderInfo.resource.extendedProps.location === parseInt($('#facilitator_location_header').val())
}

$('#facilitator_location_header').on('change',function(){
   calendar.rerenderResources();
})
```

Comment: Looking for same answers

Comment: Please provide us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then we can help you more easily. We need the HTML for your dropdown list. We need sample resource definitions. Ideally we could do with enough of the rest of your calendar config to be able to run the code above, and get the same issue. Also, do you have any debugging information? Are there any errors in your browser's Console? Have you debugged whether `resourceRender` is being executed when you call reRenderResources, and what values it's returning? etc etc.